# Data exclusions based on two-tables MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, where-clause, notin

I have table A which includes all data based on a read date. For example:

```
Read Date----Data
1/1/2016-----3
1/2/2016-----10
1/3/2016-----42
1/4/2016-----16
12/25/2016----32
12/26/2016----12
12/27/2016-----8
```

From that data set, I created a query that looks at a list of off-peak holidays, as well as off peak days, and created a table from that. This table looks like:

```
Read Date ----- Data
1/1/2016---------3
1/2/2016---------10 
12/25/2016-------32
```

I need to create a query that will give me table A data EXCLUDING table B data. Which would look something like this:

```
Read Date ----- Data
1/3/2016---------42
1/4/2016---------16
12/26/2016-------12
12/27/2016--------8
```

I have tried different join, NOT IN, WHERE NOT, and many others, which would sadly just return all results from Table A or no results at all.

PS - I apologize for the formatting, new to all of this.

NOT IN, WHERE NOT, <>, LEFT JOIN, ISNULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.read_date = a.read_date and b.data = a.data
                 );
```

Comment: IT WORKED, thank you! Just out of curiosity, what does the 1 do? I'm very new to SQL and have been teaching myself here and there, slowly learning..

Comment: @user11416683 . . . `exists` checks for the existence of rows.  It does not care what is being `select`ed.  `1` is about the simplest thing you can type.